# Gulp transpile private class methods in different files without name clashing

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using Gulp to transpile (if that's the correct term) some JS classes stored in different files, but when concatenating them at the end of my Gulp task they refer to different functions with the same name and the last one overwrites the previous ones, which I'd like to prevent.

I have something like this;

```js
class Bar {
  #variable = 'bar';

  test(obj) {
    return #variable in obj;
  }
};

class Foo {
  #variable = 'foo';

  test(obj) {
    return #variable in obj;
  }
};
```

Which results in something like this, where `_bar` is clearly duplicated;

```
"use strict";

// ...
var _bar = /*#__PURE__*/new WeakMap();
var Foo = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);
    _classPrivateFieldInitSpec(this, _bar, {
      writable: true,
      value: 'bar'
    });
  }
  _createClass(Foo, [{
    key: "test",
    value: function test(obj) {
      return _bar.has(_checkInRHS(obj));
    }
  }]);
  return Foo;
}();
"use strict";

// ...
var _bar = /*#__PURE__*/new WeakMap();
var Foo = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function Foo() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);
    _classPrivateFieldInitSpec(this, _bar, {
      writable: true,
      value: 'bar'
    });
  }
  _createClass(Foo, [{
    key: "test",
    value: function test(obj) {
      return _bar.has(_checkInRHS(obj));
    }
  }]);
  return Foo;
}();
```

Is there something I can do, in the classes themselves or Gulp configuration (Gulp plugins perhaps) so I can overcome this? I wouldn't want to have to resort to using public methods because I can not use private ones. I read I could try bundling everything with Rollup, but it's kind of a bigger change.

My Gulp task is pretty much this;

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', (cb) => {
  return (
    gulp
      .src(['foo.js', 'bar.js'])
      .pipe(
        babel({
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        })
      )
      .pipe(concat('output.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
  );
});
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use an ordinary `concat`… A simple workaround might be to concatenate the `class` definitions first and only then transpile a single file. The proper solution would of course be using modules.